# Unexpected Error (Global Variable/Enum)

Tags: java

I have written the following piece of code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Congress {
   public static int age;
   public static int ctzn;
   public static boolean eligibleForSenate() {
      if ( age >= 25 && ctzn >= 7) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
        }
  }
   public static boolean eligibleForHouse() {
     if ( age >= 30 && ctzn >= 9) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.print("Enter age of candidate: ");
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     age = sc.nextInt();
     System.out.println();
     System.out.print("Enter years of U.S. Citizenship:  ");
     ctzn = sc.nextInt();
 }
}
}
```

It gives me an error on the main line. I believe it has something to do with the global variables. How can I fix it?

Comment: typo: move the last brace before `main`...

Comment: You forgot to specify what error that is.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo ::
Change code as follow ::

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Congress {
       public static int age;
       public static int ctzn;
       public static boolean eligibleForSenate() {
          if ( age >= 25 && ctzn >= 7) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
            }
      }
       public static boolean eligibleForHouse() {
         if ( age >= 30 && ctzn >= 9) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
      }
       }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.print("Enter age of candidate: ");
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         age = sc.nextInt();
         System.out.println();
         System.out.print("Enter years of U.S. Citizenship:  ");
         ctzn = sc.nextInt();
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your braces are not matching, add one closing brace `}` before your `main` and remove one from the last line.